# Facebook iOS SDK dialog for feeds does not display properly

Tags: ios, facebook, dialog, feed

I am using Facebook iOS SDK's dialog method for feeds. I am setting, the name, caption, description, link and picture. When I display the dialog, the following display issues occur:

1. The "Cancel" and "Share" cover part of the text. When I try to scroll the dialog, these buttons scroll, too. Therefore, the covered text can never be seen.
2. The application's icon (the one before the text "via AppName") just appears as a question mark inside a blue box.

Is anyone else experiencing these issues? And is there any workaround for these?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Cancel and Share buttons are part of the html contents that are loaded within the uiwebview of the dialog. I think you could edit it somehow using the webview instance in FBDialog and the method  (NSString *)stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:(NSString *)script; but I haven't actually done so, I've just used it to ask for some part of the document.

   Take a look at this urls if you wish to dig deeper into editing the html inside the UIWebView.

   http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/windows-views/uiwebview-dynamically-modify-html-documents 
   http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/windows-views/how-to-inject-javascript-functions-into-a-uiwebview
2. To make the app icon appear, simply go to your Facebook app settings inside the developer app in FB. Then choose an icon, both its big and small images, and you're done.

Cheers.

Comment: 1. I was wondering if it's possible to fix these issues without going into the Facebook SDK code and modifying it. 2. The icon has been correctly set already in the app settings, but it still doesn't appear correctly.

Comment: I am afraid there might not be a way to do that... If you find it I'll be happy to hear about it.

Comment: I'll just mark this answer as correct. Unfortunately, I still haven't found a way to fix this without digging into the SDK code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem relies on the position of object Facebook.
If you don't put in the appDelegate as property or singleton, you will certainly experience bad positioning.

I think it's related to the params that with handleOpenUrl function the Facebook object sent to Facebook servers relating to display type and others.

I'm experiencing the same issue and, as workaround, I'm putting Facebook class only in appDelegate and the singleton class to manage this refers to it with:

```
        Facebook *fb = [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] fb];
```

The Facebook delegates are used in views and FBController (my singleton class) does only connection and data retrieval without listening to events...

Hope it helps.